# Solving for $ab=ba$ in groups in abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $a^6=1$ and $ab=ba^3$ in a group, show that $a^2=1$ & $ab=ba$.

...

I have the following for the $a^2=1$

solve for $a$ by multiplying by $b^{-1}$ on the right getting -> $abb^{-1}=ba^3b^{-1}$ -> $a=ba^3b^{-1}$.

$a^2=ba^3b^{-1}ba^3b^{-1}$ = $ba^6b^{-1} = bb^{-1} = 1$.

therefore $a^2=1$

So I really just need help proving that $ab=ba$.

Comment: $ab=ba^3=ba\cdot a^2=ba$, and you are done.

Comment: Perhaps more simply for the first:  $b=ba^6=ba^3a^3=aba^3=a^2b$

Answer (score 0):

Try to imagine the group $G$ you are working in. The first thing to note is that it has a cyclic subgroup $H$ generated by $a$ of order a divisor of $6$. The second relation tells us that $b$ acts as an automorphism on $H$ : $a^b = a^3$. Now the order of $H$ is $\in \{1,2,3,6\}$. The map $a \mapsto a^3$ is only an automorphism in the first two cases since $\operatorname{gcd}(p,n)=1$ for an automorphism $a \mapsto a^p$ of a cyclic group of order $n$. In the first two cases $H$ is the trivial group or $C_2$. In both cases we have $a^2 = 1$, so $a^3 = a$ and $a^b=a$.